# aciTree focus on Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, acitree

I'm new to aciTree, I need to know how to focus on specific node given its ID, here is the scenario:

1. user add new node through some actions and store the new model in the session
2. tree perform callback to reload the new added item
3. the tree already load the new item
4. the tree should expand and focus on the new added item -here is the problem -

I read through the documentation there exist function Focus but I don't know how to use it.

if anyone could help I'll be grateful.
Thanks in participation.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it.

```
var $aciTree = $('#aciTree');
var $itemToFocus = $aciTree.find('li#something');
var api = $aciTree.aciTree('api');

api.focus($itemToFocus);
```

If you not only want to focus the item, but also select it, try this:

```
var $selected = api.selected();
if ($selected.length !== 0) {
    api.deselect($selected);
}
if (api.isDisabled($itemToFocus)) {
    api.focus($itemToFocus);
} else {
    api.select($itemToFocus);
}
```

An even simpeler way would be to just do `$itemToFocus.click()`.